# How to override method cache settings by default in API Gateway using OpenAPI Spec?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, openapi

Here's the setup:

- We have an API Gateway that is deployed through the OpenAPI Spec.
- The API Gateway resource itself is created by terraform, but any configuration is controlled via the spec.
- We have enabled caching at a stage level, but we want the spec to control which endpoints need to be cached. This can be done via the console
- We want the caching to be "opt in" from the methods and disabled otherwise

Here's what I need help with:

- Override method settings with the OpenAPI Spec
- Add paths as cache keys and not just path parameters

Here's what I have found so far:

- `cacheKeyParameters` from the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-integration.html). The concern here is: consider 2 endpoints, `/a/b/<item_id>` and `/a/b`. The spec allows us to specify former as a cache key, but not the latter (not sure here)
- Method overrides and independent endpoint level caching found under `Stage -> Resource/Endpoint -> Method`
- Enable cache from method level settings within Stage, export the OpenAPI Spec. Search for cache related keys. No mention of "cache"

Comment: I don't understand the question here - can what you want be exactly done via the console? If so, you're looking for a way to do it via importing a spec? Can you clarify the end goal and what your last 2 bullet points mean?

Comment: >can what you want be exactly done via the console? If so, you're looking for a way to do it via importing a spec?
Yes. The method level settings especially for cache can be overridden from console. I am looking for ways to do it via OpenAPI Spec for API Gateway.

>Add paths as cache keys and not just path parameters
The spec has `cacheKeyParameters` which allows us to use path parameters as cache keys. This mean `/a/{b}` can be cached. I want to find out how to also enable cache for `/a/b` where b is not a path parameter, but part of actual path.